If there any way how we can force enable (simulate) energy saver mode in browser for test purpose?
Recently I got a task to fix how our video poster with autoplay on home page looks like when device are in energy saver mode. As I need to hide video UI and show an image banner instead of the video. But I was not able to find it in chrome flags or force enable it in settings on other browsers.
